# Code-Based Workflows in SharePoint 2013/2016

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2016

How to create a code-based SharePoint 2013/2016 workflow in Visual Studio or Microsoft has discontinued code-based workflow development? I had created sequential/state-machine workflows in SharePoint 2010. Is there something similar available in SharePoint 2013/2016 as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is there something similar available in SharePoint 2013/2016 as well?**

The `SharePoint Workflow 2010 platform` is still available in SharePoint 2013 / 2016.

**Besides,** you can develop `SharePoint 2013 Workflow Apps` in SharePoint 2013,2016. If you have [Workflow Manager](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/) that already installed and configured for your Sharepoint farm.

**For more details check,**

- [Create SharePoint workflows using Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-sharepoint-workflows-using-visual-studio).
- [Install and configure Workflow Manager for SharePoint 2013.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I guess SharePoint 2013 Workflow Apps does not support custom coding (C#) ?

Comment: Yes bro, @ZakirHC

Comment: Now this is a limitation

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the Workflow 2010 engine with the SP2013 and you would work in same way. I don't recommend 2013 workflow engine, the design of it is strange absolute headache in DR scenarios and in general we found it to be very flaky. Support on MS side not greatest, they have specialist from workflow and Sharepoint but very few that understand how those 2 integrate together. I had to rebuild WF Farm multiple times after failure and use DR procedures to restore the scopes.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Troubleshooting in WF Farm is a big challenge. Even a small problem in WF Farm needs to re-install/re-configure workflow manager